# Returning DataTables and DataSets from WCF web services

Tags: vb.net, web-services, wcf, datatable, dataset

I am looking for clarification of the behaviour of DataTables and DataSets in WCF web services.

With ASMX web services, DataTable objects are not serializable and therefore not returnable in web methods. I have always returned DataSets instead with ASMX.

I am moving to WCF services and I want to confirm that this behaviour with returning DataTables and DataSets is the same with this technology. My testing has suggested so but I'd like to confirm that this is in fact the behaviour or whether there is something that I am failing to do in order to successfully return a DataTable.

Also with returning objects of user-defined types, I have not been able to successfully return either a DataTable or a DataSet as a public property of a user-defined class.

For example, with the test class below, returning an object of type CTestClass from a WCF service returns properties DOB, Name and YearsOfAge but fails to return MyDataSet. The DataSet is created in the constructor. When I call the GetDataSet function as a public function, my WCF web service successfully returns the DataSet to the client application.

```
Public Class CTestClass

Public Sub New()
    m_myDataSet = Me.GetDataSet
End Sub

Private m_DOB As Date 
Public Property DOB() As Date
    Get
        Return m_DOB
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Date)
        m_DOB = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_sName As String 
Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_sName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        m_sName = value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_iYearsOfAge As Integer
Public Property YearsOfAge() As Integer
    Get
        Return m_iYearsOfAge
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        m_iYearsOfAge= value
    End Set
End Property

Private m_myDataSet As DataSet

Public ReadOnly Property MyDataSet() As DataSet
    Get
        Return m_myDataSet
    End Get
End Property

Private Function GetDataSet() As DataSet
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim dt As New DataTable

    ' Create new DataTable instance.
    Dim table As New DataTable
    ' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
    table.Columns.Add("Dosage", GetType(Integer))
    table.Columns.Add("Drug", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Patient", GetType(String))
    table.Columns.Add("Date", GetType(DateTime))
    ' Add five rows with those columns filled in the DataTable.
    table.Rows.Add(25, "Indocin", "David", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(50, "Enebrel", "Sam", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(10, "Hydralazine", "Christoff", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(21, "Combivent", "Janet", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(100, "Dilantin", "Melanie", DateTime.Now)
    table.Rows.Add(500, "Paracetamol", "Simone", DateTime.Now)

    ds.Tables.Add(dt)

    Return ds
End Function

End Class
```

Comment: You need to provide a setter for the serializer to work. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1702802/wcf-serialize-complex-objects-with-read-only-members

Comment: So the issue with my test class not returning a DataSet has to do with the property being read-only?

Comment: Is there some way that I can get my service to return a DataTable from a public function?

Comment: Yes, read only will not work, If you Google "wcf serialize datatable" you will see that it is non-trivial, why not return the dataset or better yet a DTO.

Answer (score 0):

OK. Removing the Read-Only attribute allowed the DataSet to be returned inside my custom object.

And I was able to return a DataTable both as the return object from a public method and from within my custom object after explicitly assigning a string value to the DataTable's TableName property.